# Using COUNTIF to return cell values instead of count

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, user-defined-functions, excel-365

This is my sheet:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Country | Employee |  | Countries | Count |
| USA | 24 |  | **Code goes here** | > 25 |
| Canada | 22 |  |  |  |
| Mexico | 36 |  |  |  |
| China | 45 |  |  |  |
| India | 12 |  |  |  |

I want to have the list of countries(*ColumnA*) that have more than 25 employees(*ColumnB*) displayed in cell **D2**

My Expected Result in Cell **D2**: Mexico, China

Is there a way to do it with COUNTIF or any other functions?

Comment: Do you mean `=ARRAYTOTEXT(filter(A2:A6,B2:B6>25))` or `textjoin(", ",1,if(b2:b6>25,a2:a6,""))`?

Comment: Or, try: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,REPT(A2:A6,B2:B6>25))` | `=ARRAYTOTEXT(TOCOL(IF(B2:B6>25,A2:A6,NA()),2))`

Answer (score 3):

### Return Matching Strings (Greater Than, Less Than)

[image]

- If you want to get creative (flexible, automatic,...) with P.b's 2nd suggestion in your comments, you can put the data in Excel (structured) tables. To also add the option `Less Than`, you could use the following formula in the first cell of the resulting (2nd) table:

```
=LET(Country,Table1[Country],Employee,Table1[Employee],
        GTLT,[@Count],Dl,", ",Er,"",
    Op,LEFT(GTLT,1),Val,VALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(GTLT,LEN(GTLT)-1))),
    tf,IF(Op=">",Employee>Val,IF(Op="<",Employee<Val,"")),
IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(Dl,1,IF(tf,Country,"")),Er))
```

- Clear the contents of the 1st column of the resulting table before entering the formula so it gets copied down.
- When you add a new value (in a new row) in any other column, the formula is automatically copied to the new row.

Comment: Making a table out of the data is a good advice. That sets the range without the need of calculations.

Answer (score 2):

For D2:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A2:A6,B2:B6>25))
```

The `FILTER` looks at the list of countries and returns those with a value about 25. The `TEXTJOIN` joins these countries together with a comma and space.

If you want to select the whole A and B columns in case the range of data gets extended, use the formula below instead:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A:A,(ISNUMBER(B:B))*(B:B>25)))
```

Comment: I think `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(A:A,IFERROR(--B:B>25,0))` would be more efficient for the whole column (2nd formula)

Comment: @P.b Still this will take more time because `FILTER()` function need to check till end of column. We can make it more efficient by using `INDEX()` like `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A))>25))`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Harun24hr. That requires the data to contain no gaps (blank rows), but in this case it would be helpful

Comment: @P.b Yes, you are right. If there is blank cells then we have apply different approach.